# What is the full text of 'Favored in Guild: Jazred Chalssin'?

Tags: dnd-3.5e

Several Assassin Handbooks out there (eg. [this one](http://www.minmaxboards.com/index.php?topic=8273.0)) seem to reference a certain feat.

> Favored in Guild – Jazred Chalssin (DMG2+web): +4 DC *[of death
>   attack]*. Tied pretty tightly with anti-Lolth rebel fluff.

I can't seem to find the given web enhancement. Even after decoding the nonfunctional link given in the handbook, it only leads [here](http://www.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/we/20060913a).

Does anybody know of the enhancement? Is there anybody who has the link or correct text?

Comment: Are you sure that's the right book? [The web enhancement archive doesn't list a DMG2 one](http://www.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/arch/we). The book itself has the feat, but there's nothing about adding to Death Attack DCs.

Comment: I am not, that is one of my problems. I am simply working with the info I have, so I cannot be sure of anything.

Comment: Fair point. :) I can confirm that Favored in Guild is a feat in DMG2, but doesn't have that ability. I can't find a web supplement for DMG2 at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Page 6 of the [*Dragons of Faerûn* Web Enhancement “City of Wyrmshadows”](http://www.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/we/20070425a) has the “Jaezred Chaulssin” criminal organization. They are a patriarchal group of shadow-draconic drow looking to undermine or overthrow Lolth’s influence on drow society so that the (mostly male-dominated) merchant houses may take control. Assassin is probably among the most common classes for them, and indeed, the Favored in Guild benefit directly improves the assassin’s death attack feature.

The rules for Favored in Guild are found in *Dungeon Master’s Guide II*.

Comment: Thanks! Seems that a misspell was the major problem, after all.

Comment: @kravaros For reference, it was a Google search for “D&D web enhancement assassin” that found it (along with a *Cityscape* web enhancement that was my first guess, the avenger April Fools’ entry, and a Mind’s Eye article).

Comment: And so we see that less is more, since highly focused searches on jazred chalssin didnt show anything.

Comment: Tbh, I didn't even consider the possibility of it being a misspell, I thought it was lost during the archivation of 3.5 stuff or something.